# Express: Automatic View Routing

Tags: node.js, express, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to create a route that automatically routes requests to a path that corresponds to a server side rendered template? Sort of like `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` does for static content?

What I mean is that I use handlebars:

```
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({
    defaultLayout: 'main'}))
```

what I find myself doing alot is doing this:

```
app.get('/home', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('home')})

app.get('/about', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('about')})

app.get('/staff/kathrin', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('staff/kathrin')})

//etc..
```

With my views being

```
/views/
   home.handlebars
   about.handlebars
   /staff/
      kathrin.handlebars
```

So I'm looking for a way to automate these routes if the requested path corresponds to a handlebars template within my /views/ directory. I obviously would need a way to deviate from that behaivour since some templates would need more/different context and also some paths have different functionality. Is there some kind of middleware that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could write some fairly simple middleware that would do that for you:

```
function render(req, res, next) {
    let path = req.originalUrl;
    // remove any query string
    let index = path.indexOf("?");
    if (index >= 0) {
        path = path.slice(0, index);
    }
    // for safety purposes, need to also skip any paths with ".." in it
    if (path.indexOf("..") >= 0) {
        next();
        return;
    }

    // remove leading /
    path = path.slice(1);

    // let res.render() tell us whether the file exists or not
    res.render(path, (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.send(html);
        }
    });
}

app.use(render);
```

Comment: Oh yeah i figured that it's not nearly as big of a deal as I thought it would be; I'm not 100% certain on how this works; this basically will take any requested path and will try to render it, if it fails it 'passes control' to the next middleware in order?

Comment: @xtr - I just added a few things you didn't have such as safety against `..` in the URL, clearing the query string and not using synchronous file I/O.  I also just let `res.render()` check the file system once and just deal with its error if present rather than check the file system first and then have it check the file system again.

Comment: @xtr - You should also load files out of a specific directory that only contains files that are supposed to be public (never the same directory as where your server JS files are).

Comment: I aciddently fatfingered after the first sentence and sent the comment. I didn't want to diminish you help! Thanks alot I can see how your code is much better than mine and has alot of advantages, thanks alot!

Comment: @xtr - Yes, it takes any path and tries to render it.   The first thing that `res.render()` will do is look for the matching template file.  If it doesn't find that, it will just call `next()` and continue routing (just like `express.static()` does).

Comment: Thanks alot for your help my views folder is nested one-level below where my code gets executed, so that should be fine. thanks alot!

Comment: @xtr - Ahhh, yes.  `res.render()` will look in the views folder for you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make jfriend00's answer more elegant/compact. The idea is his, not mine. So:

```
let viewsRouter = (req, res, next) => {
    // Path without the initial slash ("/") and removing the unsafe ".."
    let requestedPath = req.path.slice(1).replace(/\.\./g,'');
    // Now, try to render view
    res.render(requestedPath, (err,html)=>{     
        if (err) {next()}       // Not found. Check if next route applies
        else {res.send(html)}   // Found. Render view
    });
};
app.use(viewsRouter)
```